# How can I calculate all the possible combinations from these three sets of values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

Let's suppose our protagonist in this situation is named **Franz**.

Franz has:

- Three shirts, that are red, blue, and green
- Two trousers, that are blue and grey
- Two pairs of socks, that are brown and blue. (X being brown, and Y being grey)

---

Without a formula (which is what I'm looking for) I've tried to deduce the possible combinations:

S = {RBX, RBB, RYX, RYB, BBX, BBB, BYX, BYB, GBX, GBB, GYX, GYB}

---

My question is: Is there any formula/a graphic representation that could speed up the process for this?

I would really appreciate it.

---

P.S. If I'm missing something, please let me know/correct me, thanks! :)

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product ?

Comment: Do you want to enumerate all possibilities or your aim is to just find out the number of combinations?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is the intuition so you can have a "mental" graphic ^_^.

Let's say I have:

- 2 shirts: $S_1$ and $S_2$

No matter what, I only have $2$ possible outfits:$$
\{S_1, S_2\}
$$

Now, let's say I buy a pair of trousers: $T_1$. For each shirt choice I made before, I can now make that choice again with my new pair of trousers. So I have $$
\{T_1\big(S_1,S_2\big)\} = \{S_1T_1,S_2T_1\}
$$

We can then add another pair of trousers $T_2$, and you may notice that we will be able to perform each of these choices again, but with another pair of trousers:$$
\{T_1\big(S_1,S_2\big) \quad \text{and} \quad T_2\big(S_1,S_2\big)\} = 
\{S_1T_1, S_2T_1, S_3T_1 \quad \text{and} \quad S_1T_2, S_2T_2,S_3T_2\}
$$

No matter how many shirts or trousers I add, or other combinations of clothes, I am just adding that new article of clothing to a string of choices I've already been able to make.

Can you see how to add another shirt, $S_3$?

Let's say I want to add socks to my collection, so I buy 2 pairs of socks: $\mathbb{S}_1, \mathbb{S}_2$. So know I mentally take the previous list and simply "add another row" for pairs of socks:$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
\mathbb{S}_1\big(S_1T_1, S_2T_1, S_3T_1\big) &\text{and}& \mathbb{S}_1\big(S_1T_2,S_2T_2,S_3T_2\big) \\
\mathbb{S}_2\big(S_1T_1, S_2T_1, S_3T_1 \big) &\text{and}& \mathbb{S}_2\big(S_1T_2,S_2T_2, S_3T_2\big) \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Hopefully, this mental graphic helps you develop the intuition that the number of combinations of items in different sets is simply the *product* of the number of items in each set.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see any pattern in your given set $S$, I assume that you want all combinations with 1 shirt, 1 trouser and 1 pair of socks.

Given $n$ different shirts, $m$ different trousers and $k$ different socks, the total number of possibilities is just
$$
n\cdot m\cdot k
$$

Answer (score 0):

It the multiplication rule: if one event can happen in $a$ ways and another can happen in $b$ ways (and all combinations) are possible, then the two event can happen in $ab$ ways.  Think of drawing a rectangular grid, with $a$ rows and $b$ columns.  Each row represents one of the possibilities for the first event and each column represents  of the second.  There are $ab$ cells in the grid, so $ab$ different combinations of the two events.  This extends to any finite number of events.

In this case, the we have $3\cdot2\cdot2=12$ possibilities.